# ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance giving "A suitable constructor not found" for simple examples

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

So I am building a complex case here with inheritance and IOC, need to use ActivatorUtilities to inject instances and **pass parameters**... no matter what I do I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A suitable constructor for type
> 'blabla.ISimpleTest' could not
> be located. Ensure the type is concrete and all parameters of a public
> constructor are either registered as services or passed as arguments.
> Also ensure no extraneous arguments are provided.'

So in order to discard what could be the problem and ensure **there is no constructor issues**, I created a very very simple scenario that gives me the same error.

**startup.cs**

```
services.AddScoped<ISimpleTest, SimpleTest>();
```

**the class and the interface, very simple here:**

```
public interface ISimpleTest
{

}
public class SimpleTest : ISimpleTest
{
    public SimpleTest()
    {

    }
}
```

**test**

```
var theInstance = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ISimpleTest>(ServiceProvider);
```

**Additional notes**

1. The ServiceProvider instance is fine (the rest/entire application depends on it).
2. Tried with and without adding the public constructor(empty params)
3. Tried also constructor with params, same error.
4. Tried to specify the params[] parameter, by sending null or empty array, same issue.

**Extra test:**
Just to confirm it's properly registered, I tried to get the instance using the Service provider, and works without issues:

```
//No issues this way:
var yyy = ServiceProvider.GetService<ISimpleTest>();
```

What am I doing here wrong? According to documentations, this should be enough to work

Comment: What is `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`? Is that your code? If so, you're going to have to share it in order to provide a proper [mcve]. You added the service as Scoped - why? Are you resolving it from a scope? And lastly - why use the service locator pattern? It's generally consider an anti-pattern, and constructor injection is much preferred.

Comment: The error says "Ensure the type is concrete," but you are supplying the `ISimpleTest` interface. You should request the concrete type from `ActivatorUtilities` instead.

Comment: @mason you can google ActivatorUtilities, is a very well known library for DI. Scoped and Transient here has the same result, is not the issue at soon you don't use Singleton. I  can't use injection in constructor because, as the enuntiate says, "inject instances and pass parameters." which will not be decided at design time, but at execution time.

Comment: Ah okay, it's part of .NET. As your error and [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Shared/ActivatorUtilities/ActivatorUtilities.cs) points out, you must use a concrete type in order to use ActivatorUtilities. Therefore, you can't use it with an interface (or abstract class). Really seems like you need to rethink your design here.

Comment: @mason, when I use a concrete type, it does work... but what is the point of that? The idea of DI is to untie concrete references. Btw there is another method GetServiceOrCreateInstance which does resolve by using interfaces, but this one does not allow parameters for constructor. The feature i'm trying to achieve it is available in autofaq, but here seems like is not working as intended.

Comment: ActivatorUtilites does seem to be working as intended. The problem is that it's just not meant for what you're trying to do.  You can probably resolve this with some reflection. But before you do that, really ask yourself if this design is the correct one. Service locator pattern is discouraged for a reason, and you should come up with a really strong justification as to why you need it here. What's the actual use case? The code you've shown here is pretty abstract - great for a [mcve], but not so good for examining the big picture.

Comment: SLP is not anti-pattern, it has advantages and dissadvantages as ALL other patterns, but is not anti-pattern at all. The problem i'm facing is that there are third party libraries with parameter constructors that needs to be injected based on feature flags, some parameters are at execution time. This pattern is known as "Options Pattern" and is very easily achieved with Autofaq. If ActivatorUtilities can create instances, i'm wondering why does it needs the ServiceProvider as a parameter, which is mostly used to solve DI.

Comment: It needs the ServiceProvider to resolve the constructor arguments when creating the instance. Yes, service locator is an anti-pattern, as it's often abused and used in cases where it's not needed. [This seems to do what you want](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UJsRlS), you just have to create something else to register with the DI container that will tell it what type to resolve. You might be able to get a little fancier with generics or the service collection to eliminate that though.

Comment: Your example I got almost same solution by just adding other generics and stuff, I like your idea to use a provider, on my case I was using the real instance but had the problem that .... constructor with parameters. This option though adds several classes just to solve this purpose as a factory but as I might need to have factory to resolve the feature flag and pick the right implementation, it might be a 2x1. Thanks